# Can I get Safari on Mac OS X to set downloaded files' modification time to current time?

Tags: mac, safari

I've recently switched from Firefox to Safari, and basically like the change. However, one thing I liked about Firefox was that when I downloaded a file, Firefox would set the file's modification time to the time it was downloaded. Safari leaves the modification time to whatever it was on the server.

Either behavior makes sense, but I'd prefer to set the modification time to the time it was downloaded, to make it easier to find recently downloaded files. Is there any way to get Safari to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can get Safari to do it, but you can set up a [Folder Action](http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/folderactions.html) on your Downloads folder to [set the date(s) of each newly added file](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20061108143122997).